# How come attr() gives me a strange result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have:

```
<span selected="Y" onclick="change();">Click here to test~</span>


<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script>
function change()
{
  $('span[selected=Y]').attr("selected","N");
}
</script>
```

When I clicked the span, and checked the attribute of the span using firebug, the attribute "selected" changed to "selected" instead of "N".

so the result is **selected="selected"** !!??

How come it did not change to `selected="N"`

Comment: Is `selected` an valid attribute of `span`? **NO**.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `selected` is not a valid attribute on a span...

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by eligible? i thought attr() works for all kinds of attributes including self-named? no?

Comment: Since `selected` is an actual attribute that some elements have, browsers might modify your assignment to meet standards even if the element you chose doesn't support that particular attribute's special properties. Just pick a different name like "mySelected"

Comment: If you are wanting a custom named attribute, consider using a `data-` attribute, such as `data-selected`

Comment: thanks all, "data-"  solves my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selected` is not valid attribute to `span`, instead of that you can use `data`.

```
<span data-selected="Y">Click here to test~</span>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('span[data-selected=Y]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).data('selected', 'N');
});
```

Read more about jQuery **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data)**

Comment: I understand now, thanks... however, do you know any way that you can manipulate self-named attributes? something similar to attr() but checks self-defined attributes.. just curious..

Comment: "data-" solves my problem perfectly! thanks~ works like a charm.

Comment: In your first example, instead of using `.attr()`, you could use `.toggleClass('Y N')`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that for elements for which it is valid (`<option>` elements, for example), `selected` is a Boolean attribute, and the only valid value for a Boolean attribute is the name of the attribute itself. jQuery's `attr()` method is trying and failing to be clever and "correct" the value of your `selected` attribute.

Clearly jQuery doesn't handle invalid attributes correctly, which is somewhat understandable. Your options are either to use the `getAttribute()` method of the element itself (which will work in all major browsers), or better, use an attribute prefixed by `data-`, which is valid according to the HTML5 spec, supported by browsers and by jQuery.